# I'm trying to make an exit button for the page and for some reason it has error and i don't know how to solve it

Tags: python, tkinter, button, exit

I am trying to make an exit button with the code
I do import tkinter* in here

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import os

def iExit(self):
        self.iExit=tkinter.askyesno("Face Recognition","Are you sure you want to exit?")
        if self.iExit >0:
            self.root.destroy()
        else:
            return
```

and I got the error

I know that I cant put `tkinter` inside the code but i don't know how to solve it. The error that I am getting is here

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\FYP\Facial_Recognition system\Main.py", line 148, in iExit
    self.iExit=tkinter.askyesno("Face Recognition","Are you sure you want to exit?")
               ^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'tkinter' is not defined
```

Comment: You haven't imported the name `tkinter`. However, you have imported everything _from_ the `tkinter` module, so just `askyesno` instead of `tkinter.askyesno` should work.

Comment: i get the same error after i take off ```tkinter```. ```NameError: name 'askyesno' is not defined```

Comment: try `ttk.askyesno`

Comment: done trying ```ttk.askyesno``` and another different error shows up ```AttributeError: module 'tkinter.ttk' has no attribute 'askyesno'```

Comment: a simple google search for askyesno tkinter solved the problem. try `messagebox.askyesno`

Comment: i tried ```self.iExit=ttk.messagebox.askyesno``` and i got the error ```AttributeError: module 'tkinter.ttk' has no attribute 'messagebox'```. When i tried it without ```ttk``` i got this error ```NameError: name 'messagebox' is not defined```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`askyesno` is defined in the [`tkinter.messagebox`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.messagebox.html) module. Import it from there:

```
from tkinter.messagebox import askyesno
```